# Resilience4j + Spring instance of CircuitBreaker

Tags: spring, resilience4j

I would like to use Resilience4j to deal with fault tolerance, I am using `CircuitBreaker` and `TimerLimit`.

I would like to separate business logic of fault tolerance behavior, to not "dirty" my business code.

So, I am thinking to use Command pattern to execute my methods that will be treat, like Hystrix do with `HystrixCommand`.

Example:

```
public class MyCommand {

    private static final CircuitBreaker circuitBreaker;
    private Long param1, param2;
    private MyService myService;
    private static final TimeLimiter timeLimiter;

    static {
        long ttl = 50000;
        TimeLimiterConfig configTimerLimit
                = TimeLimiterConfig.custom().timeoutDuration(Duration.ofMillis(ttl)).build();
        timeLimiter = TimeLimiter.of(configTimerLimit);
       
        // I got the configuration from a class that I created.
        circuitBreaker = CircuitBreaker.of("my", CircuitBreakerConfigOptions.defaultForExternalService());
    }

    public MyCommand(Long param1, Long param2, MyService myService) {
        this.param1 = param1;
        this.param2 = param2;
        this.myService = myService;
    }

    public String run() {
        Callable<String> stringCallable = TimeLimiter.decorateFutureSupplier(timeLimiter,
                () -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> myService.hello(param1, param2)));

        Callable<String> callable = CircuitBreaker.decorateCallable(circuitBreaker, stringCallable);

        return Try.of(callable::call).recover(t -> fallback(t)).get();
    }

    protected String fallback(Throwable throwable) {
        Callable<String> stringCallable = TimeLimiter.decorateFutureSupplier(timeLimiter,
                () -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> myService.otherHello(param1, param2)));

        return Try.of(stringCallable::call).getOrElse("Fallback");
    }
}
```

Calling in my Controller:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Only to test")
@GetMapping(value = "/execute", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String execute() {
    return new MyCommand(1L, 2L, new MyService()).run();
}
```

My doubts:

1 - In this case, `circuitBreaker` really needs to be static, because I understood that the same object needs to be shared between the same method that you want to threat, I am right?

2 - How I have many instances of this application, `circuitBreaker` works individually for each instance? I am right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it seems that you are using Spring Boot, you could use the resilience4j-spring-boot-2 starter module which also has support for annotations.

https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/getting-started-3

Answer (score 2):

What I understand from your question is - You need a Resilience4j's circuit breaker which should be sperate i.e. not messed with your business logic.

So I would suggest put circuit breaker protection around run() method. below code will elaborate -

Your Controller -

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Only to test")
@GetMapping(value = "/execute", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String execute() {
    return new MyCommand().run();  
}
```

Now Write your run() method of MyCommand class with @CircuitBreaker

```
public class MyCommand {

    @CircuitBreaker(name = "RUN_METHOD_PROTECTION")        // <---- here is our circuit breaker annotation code top of below your business code... and that’s it.
    Your_Response run(Your_Request){
        // Your business logic written here...
    }
```

Further add circuit breaker configuration in your YAML property file as below (Count based I have used instead of time-based) –

```
resilience4j.circuitbreaker:
  backends:
    RUN_METHOD_PROTECTION:
      registerHealthIndicator: true
      slidingWindowSize: 100                     # start rate calc after 100 calls
      minimumNumberOfCalls: 100                  # minimum calls before the CircuitBreaker can calculate the error rate.
      permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState: 10  # number of permitted calls when the CircuitBreaker is half open
      waitDurationInOpenState: 10s               # time that the CircuitBreaker should wait before transitioning from open to half-open
      failureRateThreshold: 50                   # failure rate threshold in percentage
      slowCallRateThreshold: 100                 # consider all transactions under interceptor for slow call rate
      slowCallDurationThreshold: 2s              # if a call is taking more than 2s then increase the error rate
      recordExceptions:                          # increment error rate if following exception occurs
        - org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException
        - java.io.IOException
        - org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException
```

Now if you are unable to use annotation @CircuitBreaker in your project then you can also do things in functional way i.e.

Let say we you have defined a bean in your configuration,

```
 @Bean
 public CircuitBreaker MyCircuitBreaker(){

     CircuitBreakerConfig config = CircuitBreakerConfig.custom()
             .slidingWindow(100,100, CircuitBreakerConfig.SlidingWindowType.COUNT_BASED)
             .failureRateThreshold(50)
             .build();
     CircuitBreakerRegistry registry = CircuitBreakerRegistry.of(config);
     CircuitBreaker circuitBreaker = registry.circuitBreaker("your_run_method_CircuitBreker");  // here you are registering your circuit breaker with a unique tag. And in future you refer this tag you get a same circuit breaker.      
     return circuitBreaker;
 }
```

Now Your controller code would be below -

```
private CircuitBreaker circuitBreaker;  // Assume you have injected the value from CircuitBreaker bean 

@ApiOperation(value = "Only to test")
@GetMapping(value = "/execute", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String execute() {
    Function<Your_Request, Your_Response> decorated = CircuitBreaker
                 .decorateFunction(circuitBreaker, new MyCommand().run());

    return decorated.apply();
}
```

This way too you have never interfered with your business logic.